# How to I add a mat-icon or spreadsheet-icon in the Handson table cell?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, handsontable

Is there any way that I can add the mat-icons or the [spreadsheet-icons](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/demo-spreadsheet-icons.html) in the handsontable using Angular 8.?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @KBell I was able to achieve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by using svg tag for mat-icons and make sure, allowHtml for your column is true.